# A Color Selection Box Organized by Hue

Tags: c#, wpf

Here’s some code that generates a spread of different colors.  (It binds a `ComboBox` to the generated list of colors).

Following codes are okey.

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1"  Width="300" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    <ComboBox Margin="15" Height="30" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">

        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Height="55" Width="55" x:Name="Rectangle1">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="1000"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>

    </ComboBox>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        ColorList = ColorUtil.GenerateColorList(16);
    }

    private List<ColorWithInfo> colorList;
    public List<ColorWithInfo> ColorList
    {
        get { return colorList; }
        protected set
        {
            colorList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ColorList");
        }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "Show Hex color here, for example #0000ff ";
    }
}


public class ColorWithInfo : IComparable
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public string Info
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", Color.R, Color.G, Color.B); }
    }

    public string HueSatBright
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", Hue, Saturation, Brightness); }
    }

    public float Hue
    {
        get { return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(Color.R, Color.G, Color.B).GetHue(); }
    }

    public float Saturation
    {
        get { return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(Color.R, Color.G, Color.B).GetSaturation(); }
    }

    public float Brightness
    {
        get { return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(Color.R, Color.G, Color.B).GetBrightness(); }
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        ColorWithInfo cwiOther = obj as ColorWithInfo;

        // Sort by Hue, and then Saturation, and then Brightness
        if (this.Hue == cwiOther.Hue)
        {
            if (this.Saturation == cwiOther.Saturation)
                return this.Brightness.CompareTo(cwiOther.Brightness);
            else
                return this.Saturation.CompareTo(cwiOther.Saturation);
        }
        else
            return this.Hue.CompareTo(cwiOther.Hue);
    }
}


public static class ColorUtil
{
    public static List<ColorWithInfo> GenerateColorList(int numValsPerColor)
    {
        List<ColorWithInfo> colorList = new List<ColorWithInfo>();

        // Create increment such that we start at 0, end at 255,
        // and have a total of numValsPerColor within that range.
        int delta = Convert.ToInt32(255.0 / ((double)numValsPerColor - 1.0));

        for (int r = 0; r < numValsPerColor; r++)
            for (int g = 0; g < numValsPerColor; g++)
                for (int b = 0; b < numValsPerColor; b++)
                {
                    ColorWithInfo cwi = new ColorWithInfo
                    {
                        Color = Color.FromRgb((byte)(r * delta), (byte)(g * delta), (byte)(b * delta))
                    };
                    colorList.Add(cwi);
                }

        colorList.Sort();

        return colorList;
    }
}


}
```

My question:

I want to see selected color hex string in the TextBox1.

So, lets say I click the `ComboBox` and then click Blue color in the `ComboBox` DropDown menu. How can I see **#0000FF** in the `TextBox1`?

Comment: Get the selected item by `(ColorWithInfo)((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem` or `(ColorWithInfo)e.AddedItems[0]`.

Comment: ...and then abandon then WinForms style in WPF.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti  I have got these codes from here.  https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/12/02/962-a-color-selection-box-organized-by-hue-part-i/

Comment: @MarkMarkowitz to be on-line doesn't make it automatically _good_ WPF code! :) To be serious: in WPF you (should) seldom/almost never need to handle events directly because you're working with VM and databinding. In this case selected value is two-ways binded to a property in the VM which is (one or two-ways) binded to the value of your textbox (eventually with a ValueConverter to match the representation you want). Also that `ColorWithInfo` thing is pretty weird (and 80% useless). Here you're mixing the view with the VM...confusing and verbose (IMO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your additional question from the comments...
To Add the Hex string to each item in the ComboBox, simply alter the DataTemplate to include a TextBlock for it and bind it to the Color...

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Rectangle Height="55" Width="55" x:Name="Rectangle1">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Note: I also changed your Grid to a horizontal StackPanel too simply to get it to fit quickly. You could certainly still use a Grid or at least make the StackPanel look better but I will leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        var selectedItem = (ColorWithInfo)e.AddedItems[0];
        TextBox1.Text = selectedItem.Color.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Solved. Thank you. Lets go one step further. How can I see every hex strings on every ComboBox item in the opened DropDown ?    Because I want to see every color and every hex strings together.

Comment: You can simply change the DataTemplate for your ComboBox to show both the color rectangle and the hex string.